# topological and $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$-circle bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a closed $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$-manifold. Suppose that the underlying topological space of $M$ has a topological circle bundle structure $S^1\hookrightarrow M\to B$. Does $M$ admit a $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$-circle bundle structure?  If this is not true in general, what about the case that $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$-structure of $M$ is coming from a complex structure or even K"ahler manifold?

Comment: Yes. Since the sheaf of continuous (resp. smooth) functions on $M$ is flasque, both topological and smooth circle bundles are classified by $H^2(M,\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: @abx: The bundle is over $B$. It is true that smooth and topological circle bundles over $B$ are equivalent (I would argue that one can smoothly approximate the classifying map), but I think this question is asking something different. But this is far from my realm of expertise so I can't comment on the question further.

Comment: @Thomas Rot: Oh, right, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: It is true that this circle bundle can be smoothed, i.e. there is a smooth structure on M so that this is a smooth bundle (assuming B is a smooth manifold). This is contained in the comment of abx. However, it is not true this smooth structure must coincide with that of M. For instance, no exotic 7-sphere supports a free action of the circle. Probably the answer to your second question is also no but I don't see a counterexample right now.

Comment: I should have said: "No exotic 7-sphere supports a free action of the circle whose quotient is topologically CP^3." The proof I had in mind is that the topological manifold CP^3 admits a unique smooth structure, and the only circle bundles over CP^3 which are topologically S^7 are smoothly S^7. As for the statement about CP^3, I don't have a reference offhand, but it should be easy to find.